# Multiple processes providing DBus objects

Tags: dbus

I'm writing a program which works on a single document. If you want to open multiple documents, you simply open a process per document (yes, the process isolation is important in this case). Let’s call this these processes the servers.

Each server will provide a single object representing the document, and I’d like for client applications to be able to discover these objects. Ideally, the client interface wouldn’t be able to tell whether the documents were owned by different processes or not.

My vague solution would be to have all processes share a well-known connection name (org.example.MyApplication), and provide objects with their PID in them to avoid duplicates (/org/example/MyApplication/).
However, processes can’t share the same well-known connection name, so that’s not going to work.

I imagine I could get the client application to monitor new connections, and scan them to see if the expected object path exists, but that seems like a bad idea.

Any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: did you find any nicer solution? is there any other possibility than dbus?

Answer (score 0):

One approach, used by KDE, is to use well-known names suffixed with PIDs, like `org.kde.StatusNotifierItem-2055-1`. The client can call `org.freedesktop.DBus.ListNames` and filter the list.

Or the first server could grab the well known name and the subsequent ones would call it to register their documents, to be discoverable by clients:

```
src name = :0.42 
src path = /org/example/MyApplication/2

dest name =   org.example.MyApplication
dest path =   /org/example/MyApplication/Documents
dest method = Publish(:0.42, /org/example/MyApplication/Documents/2)
```

Comment: Hmm I don't get your second option